# Fibre bundles of fibre genus greater than 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibre-bundles

What are concrete examples of fibre bundles with fibre genus $\geq 2$? I am trying to find examples I can use to work throught the following construction:

Suppose $X \to C$ is a fibre bundle with $C$ a curve and for which the fibre $F$ is a curve of genus $\geq 2$. Then $\mathrm{Aut}(F)$ is a finite group and we can look at $\bar{F} := F/\mathrm{Aut}(F)$. We get a natural morphism $X \to \bar{F} \times C$. We can compose this with Belyi morphisms for $\bar{F}$ and $C$ to obtain a cover of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Hence with 'concrete' I mean that by following the above construction I can actually see what the resulting cover of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ looks like.

Comment: I assume that by "Belyi morphism" you mean a finite morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ that is an unbranched over away from three points of $\mathbb{P}^1$.  Why do you believe that either of $\overline{F}$ or $C$ admits a Belyi morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Belyi's theorem says: A complete nonsingular algebraic curve over a field of characteristic zero can be defined over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ if and only if it can cover $\mathbb{P}^1$ with ramification over three points. So by picking my curves to satisfy those conditions, I can be certain to find a Belyi morphism.

Comment: I know what Belyi's theorem says.  However, nowhere in your statement do you specify that your curves are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such fiber bundles are constructed in the following way : choose an étale  covering
$\tilde{C}\rightarrow C $ with Galois group $G\subset \mathrm{Aut}(F)$, and take $S=(\tilde{C}\times F )/G$, with $G$ acting on each factor in the obvious way. The fiber bundle structure is given by the first projection $S\rightarrow C$. This is quite concrete.